# Best practices for keeping custom commits for Git

Tags: git, git-submodules

Consider a scenario where I use a large code base with constant updates like OpenCV. I use OpenCV as a git submodule in my project where it points to a fixed commit so that my project can be cloned across multiple computers without worrying about updates to OpenCV affecting my project.

Now I changed a function in OpenCV to fit my needs (which I'm pretty sure won't be accepted into the main OpenCV branch), what's the best way to keep this change so that I can update the OpenCV submodule in my project from time to time to a later OpenCV commit?

Comment: Why don't you fork opencv and let you submodule point to your fork?

Comment: Create copy of OpenCV on remove you are controlling, then change address of submodule to point to your copy of OpenCV.

Comment: What @M.Spiller said, Fork your dependency, then include your fork as a submodule. You'll be able to update your fork as needed and pull the updates from upstream (the original OpenCV repo) when needed

Comment: If the maintainers won't accept your change, think reaaaaally hard whether you want to maintain a fork. It's much more work than it looks like.

Comment: As soon as you made the change, you forked from the upstream. May as well make it official.

Comment: Do you really need to change OpenCV itself? Can you not just change your own code?

Comment: For forking, is that only own Github, or can I maintain a local fork?

Also for the change, OpenCV has a default function WaterShed, I created a custom function WaterShedFloat, but the behaviour is completely changed aside from taking in floating point images, so I'm sure they won't accept the branch. But I need to do it in OpenCV because of couple defines / structures that they have and I don't want to recreate in my project

Answer (score 1):

> For forking, is that only on GitHub, or can I maintain a local fork?

First, you can [fork a repository on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo) and... never contribute back (never make a pull request)

In that fork, you can do any change you need, as well as [syncing a fork](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/syncing-a-fork), to keep it up-to-date with the upstream repository.

That way, you can reference as a submodule a repository (fork of OpenCV) that you control fully.